# WordPress allow subscriber create new Posts

Tags: wordpress, post, permissions

I like to create in my WordPress installation a Custom Post, and then allow subscribers to create posts only in that section of my installation. I don't want to allow them to add any post in normal posts or even add new tags or categories.

Is that posible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would be possible is to create a custom page type that includes a form, including only the title and content fields, which writes the new 'post' directly to the database. The user wouldn't have a lot of the actual WordPress functionality, but would get the effect you're after where they can submit content.

Another possibility, a lot less technical, would be to set up the installation with '[Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)', and then have just one separate separate "site" that users have author/editor access to, and the main site stays just as yours. They can be branded identically, and with custom navigation bars and things (which are now part of the WordPress core), as far as users could see, it would just be a section within your existing site.

I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you want with the WordPress core as it stands at the moment.

I've never seen any plugins or similar that would do this off the shelf, but I do expect it would be possible with a lot of messing around. After that much messing around with the code, it's likely that you would have lost the key Wordpress functionality, and wouldn't be able to upgrade or use certain plugins.

The only other options are creating a completely custom app, or substituting WordPress for something like Joomla!

Comment: Kind regards Matthew Higgins :) Thanks a lot